# VSCode: use chrome instead of pwa-chrome?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, vscode-debugger

I got the following JSON snippet from a coworker's launch.json file. He recommended as a way to debug client-side code from VS code. But when I inserted in my file, it complains, "replace pwa-chrome with chrome". Can someone explain what is going on? What choice is being made?

```
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
```

Comment: What VS Code version are you on? Do you have the following extension installed an enabled? `js-debug-nightly` and `debugger-for-chrome` (or the new `
ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly`)? See related GiHub issue: [#89578](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89578)

Comment: Note: When I try to use type `pwa-chrome` without any relevant extensions installed, I get this message: "_Please use type chrome instead_".

Comment: I have the same problem.  If using `type: "pwa-chrome"` everything works as expected.  If I switch to the recommended advise in the warning to use `type: "chrome"`, then I get the following error when trying to launch the debugger: "Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'chrome' (extension might have failed to activate)".  However, the chrome debugger extension was deprecated and should be native in VS Code now, so I'm also confused on the error being shown.